# Combining multiple MYSQL queries into one with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I know this subject has been covered before, and I've read about a dozen of the links provided by stackoverflow. None match my need.

I have 4 mysql queries using PHP for similar data, I'd like to lower that to one query and maybe put the results in an array that I can access. Here is my current code.

```
 $id = $row[post_id];
    $resulttwo = mysql_query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `post_id` = $id AND `meta_key` = 'length' ");
    $temptwo = mysql_fetch_array($resulttwo);       
    $length[$id] = $temptwo[0];

    $id = $row[post_id];
    $resultthree = mysql_query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `post_id` = $id AND `meta_key` = 'location_city' ");
    $tempthree = mysql_fetch_array($resultthree);
    $trailcity[$id] = $tempthree[0];

    $id = $row[post_id];
    $resultfour = mysql_query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `post_id` = $id AND `meta_key` = 'location_state' ");
    $tempfour = mysql_fetch_array($resultfour);
    $trailstate[$id] = $tempfour[0];

    $id = $row[post_id];
    unset($tempfour);
    $resultfour = mysql_query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `post_id` = $id AND `meta_key` = 'difficulty' ");
    $tempfour = mysql_fetch_array($resultfour);
    $difficulty[$id] = $tempfour[0].' difficulty';`
```

Comment: so what is  $row[post_id]; ??

Comment: It's a wordpress post ID pulled from a previous query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
$id = $row[post_id];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `post_id` = $id AND `meta_key` IN ('length', 'location_city', 'location_state', 'difficulty')");
$temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Array `$temp` will contain the `meta_key` along with the `meta_value` which you should be able to call like so `$temp[length]`. You can check the entire array with `print_r($temp);`

You should also stop writing new code using `mysql_` functions as they are [being deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql) and use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the code, and the tip, I really appreciated it. I'll test the code and report back.

Comment: Your code only returned one result
`Array
(
[meta_key] => location_city
[meta_value] => San Bernardino
`

It didn't do city, distance, state, etc.

Comment: @user1286782 That's the output of `print_r($temp)`?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, my name is Branndon, I'll update my account soon.

Comment: @user1286782 Try using `mysql_fetch_array` instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: `Array
(
[0] => location_city
[meta_key] => location_city
[1] => Pasadena
[meta_value] => Pasadena
)` @njk

Comment: any ideas as to why it's only storing one value? I'll look in to it more, it might be a nested while statement or something.

Comment: Yes, and I posted the results a few comments up from this one. @njk

Comment: @Branndon Hmm.. Try adding brackets after `$temp` ... `$temp[] = mysql...`

Answer (score 0):

This should be sufficient as you only care about the first row in each query.

```
SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = $id AND meta_key IN ("length", "location_city", "location_state", "difficulty") LIMIT 4;
```

Damn too late! :/